# JavaFX is NOT part of the JDK 14

Tags: javafx

Oracle has clearly [stated](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javafx-overview.html):

"*As of JDK 7u6 JavaFX is included with the standard JDK and JRE bundles.*"

Currently I have JDK 14 on my desktop computer; I search the entire system to find such a file as **jfxrt.jar**; but nothing found. Also `System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version")` returns null.

Additionally, I installed JavaFX SDK from [OpenJfx](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) and took a look inside its *lib* directory. The following are the only thing I found (nothing for run time; no jfxrt.jar):

[image]

Where can I download jfxrt.jar then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaFX was removed from JDK since JDK 11.
Since JDK 9, java is modular.
JavaFX was split into modules.
Hence there is no longer a single `jfxrt.jar` file. There are several JAR files, one for each module.